# How to connect Julia to Mongo Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, julia, mongodb-atlas

The package Mongoc.jl provides excellent documentation to connect to a local host, but I'm not sure how to connect to Mongo Atlas, a cloud database, via Julia.

Would love to learn how to connect the two and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Mongoc package to connect to Atlas. Just use the correct URI.

```
import Mongoc
# change <user> <pass> <db> to your username, password, database respectively
client = Mongoc.Client("mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.bpkvi0i.mongodb.net/<db>") 
# if you get TLS problem, set SSL_CERT_FILE to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt or wherever your cert/pem is
Monogc.ping(client)
```